# How do I prove that $\lim_{x\to 9} \sqrt{x}=3$ using epsilon-delta proof

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals, epsilon-delta

How do I prove that $$\lim_{x\to 9} \sqrt{x}=3$$ using epsilon-delta proof

Comment: Prove that for $\forall \varepsilon>0, |x-9|<\varepsilon$ implies $|\sqrt{x}-3|<\varepsilon$. (Hint: multiply something by $(\sqrt{x}+3)$.)

Comment: See that for  $\epsilon > |x-9|=|(\sqrt{x}-3)(\sqrt{x}+3)| \ge 3|\sqrt{x}-3|$

Comment: You're taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut: you don't need $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ to evaluate a function for an unproblematic argument. $\sqrt{9} = 3$ because $3^2 = 9$, that's it.

Comment: You might have a look at some older similar questions. For example, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450410/epsilon-delta-proof-that-lim-x-to-1-sqrtx-1 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310611/epsilon-delta-proof-of-lim-x-to-4-sqrtx-2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L$ means that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$, such that $|x-c|<\delta\ \implies\ |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ for all $x$.

Thus, let $\epsilon>0$. Then we are looking for a $\delta$ such that
$$|x-9|<\delta\ \implies\ |\sqrt{x}-3|<\epsilon$$
Now note the following equalities:
$$|\sqrt{x}-3|<\epsilon$$
$$-\epsilon<\sqrt{x}-3<\epsilon$$
$$3-\epsilon<\sqrt{x}<3+\epsilon$$
$$(3-\epsilon)^2<x<(3+\epsilon)^2$$
$$(3-\epsilon)^2-9<x-9<(3+\epsilon)^2-9$$
So given $\epsilon>0$, let $\delta=\max{|(3\pm\epsilon)^2-9|}$. Then $|x-9|<\delta$ and working our way through the above equalities from top to bottom, we see:
$$|x-9|<\delta\ \implies\ |\sqrt{x}-3|<\epsilon$$

Answer (score 2):

Start with scratch work: Assume that
$$
|\sqrt{x}-3|<\varepsilon.
$$
Now, do some work to make this look like $|x-9|$ by multiplying by $|\sqrt{x}+3|$ on both sides to get
$$
|x-9|<|\sqrt{x}+3|\varepsilon.
$$
Then, we'll choose $\delta<|\sqrt{x}+3|\varepsilon$ so that if $|x-9|<\delta$, then
$$
|x-9|<\delta<|\sqrt{x}+3|\varepsilon.
$$
We still have a pesky $x$ on the the right-hand-side of the inequality $\delta<|\sqrt{x}+3|\varepsilon$.  Since this is scratch work, we can add extra conditions as we wish.  In this case, let's say that $\delta<5$.  In this case, since we will be assuming that $|x-9|<\delta$, we know that $4<x<14$.  Therefore, $|\sqrt{x}+3|$ is bounded below by $5$ (when $x$ approaches $4$, the value of the square root approaches $2$).  Combining these facts, we want:
$$
\delta<5\quad\text{and}\quad\delta<5\varepsilon.
$$

Now, the proof begins: Let $\varepsilon>0$ and let $\delta<\min\{5,5\varepsilon\}$ (we use a minimum so that both of the inequalities that we found in the scratch work will apply).  Let $|x-9|<\delta$.  Since $\delta<5$, we know that $4<x<14$.  By the monotonicity of the square root function, we know that $2<\sqrt{x}<\sqrt{14}$ and that $5<\sqrt{x}+3<\sqrt{14}+3$.  Observe that $\sqrt{x}+3$ is positive (and never zero).  Therefore, $5<|\sqrt{x}+3|<\sqrt{14}+3$.

Next, we use the second inequality.  Since $|x-9|<5\varepsilon$, we know that $|\sqrt{x}-3||\sqrt{x}+3|<5\varepsilon$.  Since $|\sqrt{x}+3|$ is not zero (from above), we can divide by it to get
$$
|\sqrt{x}-3|<\frac{5\varepsilon}{|\sqrt{x}+3|}.
$$
We know that the denominator of the RHS is at least $5$ (and may be larger).  Therefore, you are dividing by at least $5$ and so
$$
|\sqrt{x}-3|<\frac{5\varepsilon}{|\sqrt{x}+3|}<\frac{5\varepsilon}{5}=\varepsilon.
$$
This completes the proof.

Comment: This is an old post, but I noticed that you factored $|x-9|$ wrong as $$|x-\sqrt{3}||x+\sqrt{3}|$$ instead of $$|\sqrt{x}+3||\sqrt{x}-3|$$

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven Thanks for catching the typo!  It should be fixed now.

Comment: No problemo!  Was writing a lesson, wanted some good info on $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs involving square roots.  Liked the example so when I saw there was a couple of typos, I informed you.  I screw latex up always so I like to point out issues so they can be fixed.