# Question about the inequality in the proof of $\lim_{x\to 4}{\sqrt{x}}=2$ by $\epsilon$ - $\delta$ method?

Tags: calculus, limits, inequality, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

**What I want to proof is**

$\lim_{x\to 4}{\sqrt{x}}=2$

**The following is from my textbook**

*Finding* a $\delta$. Let $\epsilon\gt 0$. We seek a $\delta\gt 0$, s.t.

$if\quad 0\lt|x-4|\lt\delta,\quad then\quad|\sqrt{x}-2|\lt\epsilon$

***To be able to form $\sqrt{x}$, we need to have $x\ge 0$. To ensure this, we must have $\delta\le 4$.***

How to derive/translate this statement in inequality?

Comment: Without context, the question cannot be answered.

Comment: I will just point out that there are some older posts about this limit or very similar limits, which might also be useful for you. For example, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310611/epsilon-delta-proof-of-lim-x-to-4-sqrtx-2 or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2034743/real-analysis-prove-limit-lim-x-to-25-sqrt-x-5

Comment: @N1ng If you look at related and linked questions (shown in the sidebar on the right) for this question - and perhaps also recursively for some of related and linked questions - you can certainly find a few more. I suppose, some of them be more useful to you, some less, but they might be worth checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note first that $|x-4|=|\sqrt x-2||\sqrt x+2|$ when $\sqrt x$ exists.

Now, let $\delta=\min(4,2\epsilon)$. Then if $|x-4|<\delta$, $\sqrt{x}$ exists (in particular, $|\sqrt x+2|\ge 2$), and

$$|\sqrt x-2|=\frac{|x-4|}{|\sqrt x+2|}\le\frac{1}{2}|x-4|<\frac{1}{2}(2\epsilon)=\epsilon.$$

Look at what has happened here. Why did we choose $\delta=\min(4,2\epsilon)$? We needed $\delta\le 4$ because this ensures that $\sqrt x$ exists, and we needed $\delta\le 2\epsilon$ to ensure that the inequality above worked out. Therefore the minimum of the two sufficed.

Edit: I will show that if $\delta\le 4$, then $|x-4|<\delta$ implies $x\ge0$.

Let $|x-4|<\delta$. If $x>4$, then of course $x>0$. Otherwise, $x\le 4$ and we have

$$4\ge\delta>|x-4|=4-x$$

which implies $0\ge -x$, i.e. $x\ge0$.

I think the way you should think of this intuitively is in terms of distances. That is, you should read $|x-4|<\delta$ as "the distance between $x$ and $4$ is smaller than $\delta$".

In particular, if $\delta\le 4$ then $|x-4|<\delta$ says "the distance between $x$ and $4$ is less than $4$", which means $x$ must be greater than $0$.

Comment: Your answer is very clear. But I still can't get it how to write down $\delta\le 4$ implies $\sqrt{x}$ exists...

Comment: @N1ng yes, my apologies. See my edit